# PHP ODBC connection path to the database

Tags: ubuntu, php, database, odbc

I am trying to run the PHP function to make an ODBC connection like this:
$conn   = odbc_connect('db_name', 'usr', 'password');

And I get this error:

Connect failed to localhost:1111 = localhost:1111., 
SQL state S2801 in SQLConnect

Which makes me think that the path to the database needs to be specified.  Is that correct?  If so, is there a way to find out which directory the database is in without browsing through every directory and looking for it manually?

I am using Ubuntu OS.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: The first option to [odbc_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) is a [DSN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_Source_Name), not the name of the database.  The options for a DNS depend a lot on ODBC driver, and what database you are using.